# How to scrape Amazon Today's Deals page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-playwright

I want to scrape [Amazon Today's Deals page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox). So you know Amazon Today's Deals page has an reactjs so all the deals dynamicly loading. So I am using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) with [Playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright).

I am using xpath for getting the deals. I tested in the browser inspect. This xpath "//*[@id="grid-main-container"]//*[@aria-label="Deals grid"]//*[@data-testid="grid-deals-container"]//*[@data-testid="deal-card"]/a/@href"get all the deals in the page.

When I run my code just getting 30 deals but deals page has a 60 deals. Have can I get the all the deals. What am I wrong? Thank you so much for your helping to me. And thank you so much for taking your time.

**This is my code:**

```py
import logging
import scrapy

class Amztest1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amztest1"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta=dict(
            playwright = True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            errback=self.errback,
        ))

    async def parse(self, response):
        product_count = len(response.xpath('//*[@id="grid-main-container"]//*[@aria-label="Deals grid"]//*[@data-testid="grid-deals-container"]//*[@data-testid="deal-card"]/a/@href').getall())

        logging.debug(f"PRODUCT COUNT: {product_count}")
  
    async def errback(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
```

**This is my settings file:**

```py
BOT_NAME = "test1"

SPIDER_MODULES = ["test1.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "test1.spiders"

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True

REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"

PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE = "chromium"

PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS = {
    "headless": True,
    "timeout": 20 * 1000,  # 20 seconds
}

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

**This is my logs:**

```py
2023-06-27 22:07:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.9.0 started (bot: test1)
2023-06-27 22:07:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.14, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 23.2.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023), cryptography 41.0.1, Platform macOS
2023-06-27 22:07:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'test1',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True,
 'LOG_FILE': 'amz.log',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'test1.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['test1.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor',
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
               'like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
2023-06-27 22:07:11 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: KqueueSelector
2023-06-27 22:07:11 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-06-27 22:07:11 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop
2023-06-27 22:07:11 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware']
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem cache storage in /scrapy_tests/test1/test1/.scrapy/httpcache
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Starting download handler
2023-06-27 22:07:12 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Starting download handler
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox?ref_=nav_cs_gb> (referer: None) ['cached']
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [root] DEBUG: PRODUCT COUNT: 30
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 597,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1040282,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 5.221396,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 27, 19, 7, 17, 493559),
 'httpcache/hit': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 12,
 'memusage/max': 61661184,
 'memusage/startup': 61661184,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 27, 19, 7, 12, 272163)}
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing download handler
2023-06-27 22:07:17 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing download handler
```

Comment: Those missing deals are loaded in real-time using API requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. You know all deals are loading real-time so you need to wait load the all deals. So used some meta tags for the div of deal and this way solve the issue.

This is my code:

```py
import logging
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class Amztest1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amztest1"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com/deals'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_deals_list, 
            meta={
                "playwright" : True,
                "playwright_include_page" : True,
                "playwright_page_methods" :[
                        PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div#grid-main-container', timeout=0),
                        PageMethod("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"),
                    ],
                "playwright_context_kwargs": {"ignore_https_errors": True,},
                "playwright_page_goto_kwargs": {"wait_until": "networkidle",},
                "errback":self.errback,
                }
        )
```

This is my settings file:

```py
BOT_NAME = "test1"
SPIDER_MODULES = ["test1.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "test1.spiders"
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"

PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE = "chromium"

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT = 0
```